# How to update a varchar2 column to be a string + number value from another column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle db table that has a lot of data in it and I need to modify table's columns.  Basically something like:

```
TABLER: USERS
COL: id: long
COL: username: varchar2(255)
```

'id' column contains numbers like: `1000, 1001, 1002`

I need to replace the 'id' column with a new 'user_id' column that is a varchar2(255) and the format will be like: `user-1000, user-1001, user-1002`

My plan is (A) add the new 'user_id' column, (B) copy the 'id' value over, then (C) delete the original 'id' column.

This is adding the new column:

```
alter table user_table add (user_id varchar2(255));
```

This will copy the 'id' number value to the new 'user_id' column ...

```
update user_table set user_id = id;
```

But how can I set the value in 'user_id' to "user-1000", "user-1001", and so on?

Seems like I need something like:

```
update user_table set user_id = 'user-'+id;
```

Comment: Your `update` will work if you change `+` to `||`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Thanks, worked!  Add an answer and I'll mark it correct!

Comment: @GriffeyDog This is not so easy with `long` datatype because of [restrictions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-A3C0D836-BADB-44E5-A5D4-265BA5968483): *In addition, LONG columns cannot appear in these parts of SQL statements: SQL built-in functions, expressions, or conditions*

Comment: If _all_ of the new values are going to start with the same literal string, then what's the point of creating this column in the first place?  What _business problem_ is this meant to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Your `update` statement is almost correct. Use the Oracle concatenation operator `||` instead of `+`, and it should work.